# Rolling Time LookBack Calculation

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm sorry if this has been answered.  I've been searching around for awhile now.

I have a times series dataset that I need to perform calculations on based on the previous x time (last hour,day, etc).

My issues is that I don't know how to run these calculations since the time deltas are not standardized.

Example:

Column A - Time (in seconds lets say)

Column B - Value

```
Time  Value  Result(5)
01     3      0
02     5      3
04     4      8
07     8      9 
09     6      12
13     4      6
14     4      10
15     1      8
22     9      0
33     7      0
```

How could I return the Result(5) column by summing the last 5 seconds from that one instance (row) (not including it)?

Thank you.

EDIT:

To clear up what I'm trying to do:

1) Find the previous 5 secs of data using column A and return that range of rows

2) Using that range of rows for the 5 previous secs, sum column B

3) Output in Column C (formula)

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should do what you need (paste into C2 and drag down):

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11,">="&A2-5,$A$2:$A$11,"<"&A2)
```

Where YourTime is the time in the row you wish to look back and sum over.

I've tested and it works for the data you provided - expand the ranges as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Mike!

I tried the formula and couldn't get it to work.

I was trying to have the formula in column C where I could drag/copy it down as time moves one (rows go lower). 

I was a little thrown off with the column C inputs in your formula.  I tried using Column Bs and still couldn't get it to work.

I added to my question above under EDIT: to hopefully clear up my problem.

Comment: Hi Scott - I edited my response above and have tested it. Hope that works for you!